# console.log("this.length--->" + this.length); this behaviour

Tags: javascript, html

- I am trying to learn js basics.
- I tried analysing the string count code but I am not sure about certain statements.
- can you guys tell me why it's behaving in such a way?
- this will help to understand better and in future, I can fix the issues by myself.
- providing code below

```or-tag-here
String.prototype.count=function(c) { 
  var result = 0;
  var i = 0;
  console.log("this--->" + this); // how come this prints strings here, since we dont pass stings here
  console.log("this.length--->" + this.length);
  for(i;i<this.length;i++)
    {
        console.log("this[i]--->" + this[i]); // here we did not declare this an array anywhere right then how come its taking this[i] as s and stings also we did not put in any array
      console.log("c--->" + c);
        if(this[i]==c)
        {
            result++;
          console.log("inside if result++ ---->" + result++);
          // here it prints 1 and 3 but only two times s is present so it should print 1 and 2 right
        }
     }
    console.log("out of for loop result--->" + result);
    // how its printing 4 but s is present only two times 
  return result;
  //console.log("out of for loop result--->" + result);
};


console.log("strings".count("s")); //2


output

this--->strings
  this.length--->7
  this[i]--->s
  c--->s
  inside if result++ ---->1
  this[i]--->t
  c--->s
  this[i]--->r
  c--->s
  this[i]--->i
  c--->s
  this[i]--->n
  c--->s
  this[i]--->g
  c--->s
  this[i]--->s
  c--->s
  inside if result++ ---->3
  out of for loop result--->4
  4
```

Comment: this is your string "strings" and you have 2 s in the this string but you are doing result++ two times so 1,2,3,4 and you print the 1 and 3 ... then out of the loop 4

Comment: and a string is like an array so this[i] is valid

Answer (score 0):

`console.log("this--->" + this); // how come this prints strings here, since we dont pass stings here`

That prints a string because you have a string + something.  This is called string concatenation and the result of string concatenation is a string.  In this case, `this` is the object that called the count function which was a string.

`console.log("this[i]--->" + this[i]); // here we did not declare this an array anywhere right then how come its taking this[i] as s and stings also we did not put in any array`

`this` is a string.  Bracket notation on a string will return the char at the provided index.

`result++;
 console.log("inside if result++ ---->" + result++);
 // here it prints 1 and 3 but only two times s is present so it should print 1 and 2 right`

the `result++` notation is the same as `result += 1`, but `result++` does the addition of 1 AFTER the value is evaluated while `++result` will do it before.  So in this example the order of events is: 
add 1 to the result, then print the `console.log`, then add 1 to the result

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Questions from your code example are basicly about 2 issues:

1. *this* - is JS keyword. You don't have to initialize it, it automatically defined everytime, everywhere in your JS code. And it could mean different things in different situations, but it's too advanced topic if you've just started learning JS. For now lets just say, that `this` refers to the context, that called `count()` function, which is the string `"strings"`. So it has length and you can iterate over it as an array of characters
2. Why the count rose to number 4, when it should be 2? Because when you found a match between current letter of the string and the character `"s"` (line with `this[i]==c`) you increment the result by 1 using `result++`. But you do it also in your `console.log` right after it, so it gets increased by 2 every time it finds a match

Comment: hey I did not understand second one...can you explain in detail

Comment: @arkr In your for loop, you are looping through all characters of `"strings"` and matching them with `"s"`. When that happens you do these two things: `result++;` and `console.log("inside if result++ ---->" + result++);`. Notice the **result++** in both commands. You increment your result count 2 times for every match. That's why you get result 4 instead of 2